# Picking random sub-routines from a list

Tags: python, list, random, python-3.3, subroutine

This is for Python 3.3. When I run this program it always runs the sub-routine "func_addition".

I want to make it so that it picks a random sub-routine from the list. So, it will ask a random arithmetic question.

```
import random
def func_addition():
    a = random.randint(1,25)
    b = random.randint(1,25)
    c=a+b
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(a)+" + "+str(b)+" ? "))   

def func_subtraction():
    d = random.randint(10,25)
    e = random.randint(1,10)
    f=d-e
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(d)+" - "+str(e)+" ? "))

def func_multiplication():
    g = random.randint(1,10)
    h = random.randint(1,10)
    i=g*h
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(g)+" X "+str(h)+" ? "))

my_list=[func_addition() , func_subtraction() , func_multiplication()]

name=input("What is your name ? ")
print("Hello "+str(name)+" and welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz")
print(random.choice(my_list))
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parens or you will call all the functions when the list is created.

```
my_list = [func_addition , func_subtraction , func_multiplication]

name = input("What is your name ? ")
print("Hello {} and welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz".format(name))
chc = random.choice(my_list) # pick random function
chc() # call function
```

You don't seen to use your variables, I would do something like the following to validate the answer:

```
def func_addition():
    a = random.randint(1,25)
    b = random.randint(1,25)
    c = a + b
    answer = int(input("What is {} + {} ? ".format(a,b)))
    if answer == c:
        print("Well done, that is correct")
    else:
        print(" Sorry, that is incorrect, the correct answer is {}".format(c))
```

Comment: I tried my_list=[func_addition , func_subtraction , func_multiplication] WITHOUT PARENTHESES. But, when I run it, it says:  What is your name ? Thifyan
Hello Thifyan and welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz
<function func_multiplication at 0x02B1BFA8>

Comment: @ThifyanRavinehru you are printing the function you are choosing. You need to run it instead with random.choice(my_list)()

Comment: Can you please post the whole code at once. I am confused. Thank you

Comment: @ThifyanRavinehru, replace your last four lines with the lines I just added

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def func_addition():
    a = random.randint(1,25)
    b = random.randint(1,25)
    c=a+b
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(a)+" + "+str(b)+" ? "))   

def func_subtraction():
    d = random.randint(10,25)
    e = random.randint(1,10)
    f=d-e
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(d)+" - "+str(e)+" ? "))

def func_multiplication():
    g = random.randint(1,10)
    h = random.randint(1,10)
    i=g*h
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(g)+" X "+str(h)+" ? "))

my_list=[func_addition , func_subtraction , func_multiplication] #without parentheses

name=input("What is your name ? ")
print("Hello "+str(name)+" and welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz")
random.choice(my_list)()
```

Comment: Two times `random.choice`?

Comment: @Matthias thanks, forgot to remove the print statement.

Comment: I tried my_list=[func_addition , func_subtraction , func_multiplication] WITHOUT PARENTHESES. But, when I run it, it says: What is your name ? Thifyan Hello Thifyan and welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz <function func_multiplication at 0x02B1BFA8>